# VB.NET Trying to draw a line

Tags: vb.net, winforms, turtle-graphics

I am creating a program where the user can command a turtle which moves around on a a white panel named panel 1. I have made the turtle rotate using`rotatefliptype` 
I am now in the process of making a line follow behind it. I've had a few ideas including placing pixels in places that meet the requirement. My one problem is the location. Is it possible to make the location relative to a certain point?
My current code is:

```
Sub imageCloner(clonedImage As Image, clonedWidth As Int16, clonedHeight As Int16, clonedLocation As Point)
    'clone image
    Dim dotImage As New PictureBox()
    dotImage.Image = clonedImage
    dotImage.Location = clonedLocation
    dotImage.Width = clonedWidth
    dotImage.Height = clonedHeight
    dotImage.SizeMode = picBoxTurtle.SizeMode
    panel1.Controls.Add(dotImage)
End Sub
Sub findGradient()
    'gradient = rise / run
    turtleMovementGradient = (turtleYLocation - turtleOriginalYLocation) / (turtleXLocation - turtleOriginalXLocation)
End Sub
Sub drawLine()
    find the gradient
    findGradient()

    create variables
    Dim xcounter As Int16 = 0
    Dim ycounter As Int16 = 0

    For ycounter = 1 To panel1.Height
        For xcounter = 1 To panel1.Width
            If ycounter / xcounter = turtleMovementGradient Then
                imageCloner(blackDotOnePixel.Image, 1, 1, New Point(panel1.Width - xcounter, panel1.Height - ycounter))
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

The drawLine() subroutine is run first.
I NEED HELP WITH THE DRAWING OF THE LINE

Answer (score 0):

This should give you some idea.

```
Private Sub Panel1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Panel1.Paint
    ' Create a local version of the graphics object for the Panel.
    Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
    ' Draw a string on the Panel.
    g.DrawString("This is a diagonal line drawn on the control", New Font("Arial", 10), Brushes.Red, New PointF(30.0F, 30.0F))
    ' Draw a line in the Panel.
    g.DrawLine(System.Drawing.Pens.Red, Panel11.Left, Panel1.Top, Panel1.Right, Panel1.Bottom)
End Sub
```

Comment: What do I have to put in the **parentheses** to run this subroutine

Comment: It is an event, so it will be called whenever the control needs repainting, if you include that in your program, you should see the text and the line on the control.